# How is van Kortryk's identity used?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, propagator

The Wikipedia article on propagators mentions
that the harmonic oscillator propagator can be derived
from the free particle
propagator using van Kortryk's identity.
This is followed by the identity itself which
appears formidable.
It is not clear to me how to even begin with this.
How is van Kortryk's identity used?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator

Comment: [e-print](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.14401.pdf).

Comment: Proven in [this footnote](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/778637/66086).

Comment: Consider to include van Kortryk's identity in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H$ be the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian.
$$
H=\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2\hat x^2}{2}
$$

Let $K(b,a)$ be the propagator for the harmonic oscillator.
\begin{equation*}
K(b,a)=\langle x_b|\exp\left(-\frac{iHt}{\hbar}\right)
|x_a\rangle
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}

This is van Kortryk's identity.
\begin{equation*}
\exp\left(-\frac{iHt}{\hbar}\right)=
\exp\left(-\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar}\hat x^2\tan\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2m\omega\hbar}\hat p^2\sin(\omega t)\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar}\hat x^2\tan\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)
\tag{2}
\end{equation*}

Substitute (2) into (1) to obtain
\begin{equation*}
K(b,a)=\langle x_b|\exp\left(-\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar}\hat x^2\tan\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2m\omega\hbar}\hat p^2\sin(\omega t)\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar}\hat x^2\tan\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)
|x_a\rangle
\end{equation*}

Replace operator $\hat x$ with its eigenvalues.
\begin{equation*}
K(b,a)=
\exp\left(-\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar}x_b^2\tan\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)
\langle x_b|\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2m\omega\hbar}\hat p^2\sin(\omega t)\right)|x_a\rangle
\exp\left(-\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar}x_a^2\tan\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)
\tag{3}
\end{equation*}

Let
$$
K_0(b,a)=\langle x_b|\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2m\omega\hbar}\hat p^2\sin(\omega t)\right)|x_a\rangle
$$

Substitute $T$ for $\sin(\omega t)/\omega$.
$$
K_0(b,a)=
\langle x_b|\exp\left(-\frac{iT}{2m\hbar}\hat p^2\right)|x_a\rangle
$$

$K_0$ is now a free particle propagator hence
$$
K_0(b,a)=\biggl(\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar T}\biggr)^{1/2}
\exp\biggl(\frac{im}{2\hbar T}(x_b-x_a)^2\biggr)
$$

Substitute $\sin(\omega t)/\omega$ for $T$.
\begin{equation*}
K_0(b,a)=\biggl(\frac{m\omega}{2\pi i\hbar\sin(\omega t)}\biggr)^{1/2}
\exp\biggl(\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar\sin(\omega t)}(x_b-x_a)^2\biggr)
\tag{4}
\end{equation*}

Substitute (4) into (3) and combine exponentials.
$$
K(b,a)=\biggl(\frac{m\omega}{2\pi i\hbar\sin(\omega t)}\biggr)^{1/2}
\exp\left(-\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar}\left(x_b^2+x_a^2\right)\tan\frac{\omega t}{2}
+\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar\sin(\omega t)}(x_b-x_a)^2\right)
$$

By the identity
$$
\cot\theta=-\tan\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{1}{\sin\theta}
$$

we have
$$
K(b,a)=\biggl(\frac{m\omega}{2\pi i\hbar\sin(\omega t)}\biggr)^{1/2}
\exp\left(\frac{im\omega}{2\hbar}\left(x_b^2+x_a^2\right)\cot(\omega t)
-\frac{im\omega}{\hbar\sin(\omega t)}x_bx_a\right)
$$

The last result is equivalent to
the propagator in Wikipedia.